# Xamarin Component Submission - Unable to extract XPKG archive on Windows

Tags: windows, xamarin, xamarin-component

I am trying to create  a xamarin XPKG for component submission as described [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/submitting_components/component_submission_quickstart/).

In Xamarin components store, Xamarin has provided a [link to download .exe file](https://components.xamarin.com/submit/xpkg) for creating the Xamarin package which has to be extracted.

But, for some reason, I am unable to extract that file after downloading. It is not a zip file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just tried downloading the file on OS X, and it is `.zip` container. Are you possibly running on Windows? Also, are you certain that the file extensions in your OS is simply not hidden? Lastly, what happens if you add the `.zip` extension yourself?

Comment: @Demitrian I am running it on windows.Also I am pretty sure  that file extensions are not hidden.other zip files are showing .zip extension.I do not quite understand .add the .zip extension yourself?

Comment: Just rename the file and add `.zip` to the end of the filename. What happens then?

Comment: @Demitrian yeah.thanks.It's working.I got the xamarin-component.exe.what should I do next?when I have pressed the .exe file it is just appears and disappears.

Comment: Good to know. Just follow the steps as mentioned in the [guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/submitting_components/component_submission_quickstart/). Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the proper file extension wasn't added when downloading the archive to Windows. The solution is to simply re-name the file and add `.zip` at the end.